# Vsphere Esxi 5.5 only shutdown permission to local user

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, esxi

I have created a normal user in ESXi, I want to allow that user to shutdown the ESXi server directly from console by pressing F12 key. I have given this permission (Host’ –> Configuration –> ‘Power) to that user. By pressing F12 key, I have entered the login name and password. Then its showing this message "User does not have permission to login to DCUI". So I add the local user to DCUI access permission. Now able to login and able to shutdown. But the user able to change other settings also like reset the configuration, changing the Network seetings, etc..

I want to allow the user to shutdown the ESXi server only. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Lockdown mode you can do this. But it needs Vcenter to login normally. I have read that DCUI disables administrator privileges when Lockdown mode is enabled. So you can configure the privileges.

> When you disable lockdown mode using the DCUI, all users with the DCUI Access privilege are granted the Administrator role on the host.